# How to run external tool on current file in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

I need to upload currently edited JSPs to server - via scp. I have pscp on my path on my windows machine.

How do I setup inteliij idea to do this with one click for currently opened file?

(I would be able to set this up in eclipse - via 'run tool' and parameter placeholders)

Comment: The same -- just **Settings | External Tools**. There will options where to show such entry (what menu/context menu). Once done -- right click (in Editor or Edit Tab or Project View panel) and invoke it from there (or you can assign custom shortcut in "Settings | Keymap | External tools").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA this feature is called [External Tools](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-third-party-tools.html). There are various variables that you can pass to the process, including the current file name (`$FilePath$`).

Comment: I had some problem propagating this setting to rightlocations

Comment: The variable name of the current editor file is $FilePath$