# Any easy way to open IntelliJ workspace file in notepad++

Tags: intellij-idea, notepad++, intellij-plugin

I am new to IntelliJ, previously I used Eclipse as my IDE.

During that time, I used to drag and drop the file in Eclipse workspace to Notepad++, so that I could open it directly in Notepad++.

Now I am following the same steps in IntelliJ, however, it will just paste the file path in Notepad++, which is not what I want.

Also, I know that I can use the "Show in Explorer" function in IntelliJ to locate the file first, and then open it in Notepad++. 
But this is too inconvenient, so I come here to ask if there is any other easy way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Are you saying that `.idea` files don't open in Notepad++ when dragging and dropping?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/413524/how-do-i-get-notepad-to-associate-a-file-type-with-a-language

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not only .idea file, but also other files like java files and xml files. Sometimes I want to open xml file in Notepad++ rather than in IntelliJ.

Comment: You can create an external tool that will open the current file in external editor, then invoke it via the context menu or assign a keyboard shortcut to this tool. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13421592/104891).

Comment: @CrazyCoder It is a better choice, thanks a lot.